# Linux Terminal: fill out form using cURL

Tags: html, linux, forms, curl, terminal

I am experimenting with cURL in Linux Terminal.  I am trying to fill out a simple form, but I am unsure how I can check to see if I actually filled the form out.  The command example I am using is: `curl --data "firstname=Johnny" http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp`

Am I actually filling out the form?  How do I check? Does anyone know of any more sound examples of a form being filled out with cURL via Terminal?